# nodejs-websocket unhandled error

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to node.js and server-side in general.

I am working on a webapp with a node.js server-side, and have gotten mostly everything working using websockets. One problem I am having, though, is that when I close a tab, my server crashes with the error:

```
events.js:182
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
```

Heres my server-side code:

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket")
var owjs = require("overwatch-js");
var fs = require("fs");

console.log("Opening server on port 8003...");

var options = {
    secure: true,
    key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem")
}

var server = ws.createServer(options, function (conn) {

    // When we get a username
    conn.on("text", function (str) {

        // Get user stats
        owjs
            .getOverall('pc', 'us', str)
            // Send data back to client
            .then((data) => conn.sendText(JSON.stringify(data)));

    });

    conn.on("close", function (code, reason) {
        console.log("Connection closed")
    });

}).listen(8003);
```

I'm pretty sure I need to handle the error (obviously) but dont know how to do it. Do I use .on("error") after .listen? I tried that but i'm not sure if I did it right.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you shure *key.pem* and *cert.pem* exist?

Comment: That's not the problem - the server works fine. It only dies when I close a tab.